# cordova: intermittent out-of-memory condition on iOS in WebCore?

Tags: cordova, memory-leaks

I have a cordova app that's working well in android, debugging it now in ios. I need some help in figuring out how to proceed with debugging on the memory exception described. Thanks ...

Details:

```
Mac mini
OSX Yosemite 10.10.5
Xcode 7.2.1
Cordova 6.0.0
```

One page (used to encode audio files), sometimes operates just fine, and at other times, never reaches an xcode breakpoint set as early as possible in the javascript for that page ("js/audio_files.js"), and throws a memory exception (EXC_BAD_ACCESS in bmalloc::VMHead::grow), with about 1.44GB (yes, GB) memory allocated. The exception occurs about 60% of the time.

The data below is from the xcode debugger when targeting the iPhone-4s emulator. The fault occurs either from xcode or when using "cordova run ios --target="iPhone-4s"" from Terminal/bash.

When the exception occurs, the elements of the page appear, minus the icons established in on_device_ready (which is never reached, nor is the line with the call to addEventListener). Then there is about a 1-minute pause, and xcode stops at the problem in bmalloc:VMHeap:grow in thread "WebThread".

The stack trace for "WebThread" follows. I can't provide data on the argument values, since the lldb console in xcode doesn't respond to any of the debug commands, and I have not yet discovered how to spawn an external instance of lldb targeted to the ios emulator.

```
#0  0x0b51e966 in bmalloc::VMHeap::grow() ()
#1  0x0b51cca6 in bmalloc::Heap::allocateSmallPage(std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, unsigned long) ()
#2  0x0b51cab2 in bmalloc::Heap::refillSmallBumpRangeCache(std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, unsigned long, bmalloc::FixedVector<bmalloc::BumpRange, 32ul>&) ()
#3  0x0b51b131 in bmalloc::Allocator::allocateBumpRangeSlowCase(unsigned long) ()
#4  0x0b51b2b7 in bmalloc::Allocator::allocateSlowCase(unsigned long) ()
#5  0x0b4ef9a0 in WTF::fastMalloc(unsigned long) ()
#6  0x097ab757 in WebCore::DOMTimer::install(WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext&, std::__1::unique_ptr<WebCore::ScheduledAction, std::__1::default_delete<WebCore::ScheduledAction> >, int, bool) ()
#7  0x097bab1f in WebCore::DOMWindow::setTimeout(std::__1::unique_ptr<WebCore::ScheduledAction, std::__1::default_delete<WebCore::ScheduledAction> >, int, int&) ()
#8  0x09bba620 in WebCore::JSDOMWindow::setTimeout(JSC::ExecState*) ()
#9  0x09bb5b1e in WebCore::jsDOMWindowPrototypeFunctionSetTimeout(JSC::ExecState*) ()
#10 0x1238463d in 0x1238463d ()
#11 0x123eb1b1 in 0x123eb1b1 ()
#12 0x123e7eb1 in 0x123e7eb1 ()
#13 0x123efdbb in 0x123efdbb ()
#14 0x0b361934 in llint_entry ()
#15 0x0b35d477 in vmEntryToJavaScript ()
#16 0x0b2247dc in JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) ()
#17 0x0b209ca9 in JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) ()
#18 0x0afacfa1 in JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) ()
#19 0x0a1674b1 in WebCore::ScheduledAction::executeFunctionInContext(JSC::JSGlobalObject*, JSC::JSValue, WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext&) ()
#20 0x0a16703b in WebCore::ScheduledAction::execute(WebCore::Document&) ()
#21 0x0a166f49 in WebCore::ScheduledAction::execute(WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext&) ()
#22 0x097ac03c in WebCore::DOMTimer::fired() ()
#23 0x0a356a30 in WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() ()
#24 0x0a3568c6 in WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFired() ()
#25 0x0a1c242f in WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) ()
#26 0x00d94f56 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#27 0x00d94952 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#28 0x00d52c3a in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#29 0x00d520e6 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#30 0x00d51efb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#31 0x0a3d72f0 in RunWebThread(void*) ()
#32 0x039b9c25 in _pthread_body ()
#33 0x039b9b9b in _pthread_start ()
#34 0x039b6e32 in thread_start ()
```

The html for this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script id="audio-tpl" type="text/template">
    <p id="{{title_id}}" class="title"></p>

    <div id='{{player_id}}' class='contents'>
        <div id='{{file_name}}' class='player_state'/>
        <div id='{{player_state}}' class='player_state'/>
        <button id='{{record_start_id}}' class='{{plr_ctl_class}}' hidden></button>
        <button id='{{record_stop_id}}' class='{{plr_ctl_class}}' hidden></button>
        <button id='{{play_start_id}}' class='{{plr_ctl_class}}' hidden></button>
        <button id='{{play_pause_id}}' class='{{plr_ctl_class}}' hidden></button>
        <button id='{{play_stop_id}}' class='{{plr_ctl_class}}' hidden></button>
        <button id='{{play_rewind_id}}' class='{{plr_ctl_class}}' hidden></button>
        <button id='{{eject_id}}' class='{{plr_ctl_class}}' hidden></button>
        <br/>
        <button id='{{upload_id}}' class='{{button_class}}'>Upload</button>
        <br/>

        <div id='{{error_id}}' class='error'/>
        <div id='{{file_list_div_id}}'/>
        <div id='{{log_id}}'/>
    </div>

</script>

<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js_lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="js_lib/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="js_lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/title.js"></script>
<script src="js/html_utils.js"></script>
<script src="js/audio_files.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```